# Unity3D: Accessing a Method from the only script available in a transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Scenario:**

I have 10 objects in a scene. Each Object has a unique class attached. On clicking one object, Two methods need to be called.

- A method in a script attached to the clicked gameObject. (To enable the newly clicked object's UI)
- A method from the previously clicked gameObject. (To disable the previously clicked object's UI)

**What I've done:**

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
hit.transform.GetComponent(hit.transform.name+"").Show_status (true);
current_transform.GetComponent(current_transform.name+"").Show_status(false);
current_transform = hit.transform;
}
```

Here, I am trying to access the Script using the string as the script is named after the gameObject itself. A method named "Show_status()" is available for all the classes. The above code produces the below error.

> "UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for
>   `Show_status"

Also, if this isn't possible the way I'm attempting it, it would be helpful to mention some other simple approaches to solving the scenario.

Comment: GetComponent has a form that does the casting for you, i.e. `myGameObject.GetComponent<MyClass>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing GameObject by name is slow. `hit.transform.name` is slow and allocates memory each time it is called. Getting component by string name(`GetComponent(string)`) is slow too.

> if this isn't possible the way I'm attempting it, it would be helpful
>   to mention some other simple approaches to solving the scenario.

This can easily be done with an `Interface`.

Create a simple script called `IClickable` *This is not a class. It is an interface*.

```
public interface IClickable
{
    void Show_status(bool value);
}
```

Your `10` Scripts(Implement `IClickable` in each one):

Script1 called `ObjectToClick1`.

```
public class ObjectToClick1 : MonoBehaviour, IClickable
{
    //Implement your interface function
    public void Show_status(bool value)
    {
        //Your implementation here
    }
}
```

Script2 called `ObjectToClick2`.

```
public class ObjectToClick2 : MonoBehaviour, IClickable
{
    //Implement your interface function
    public void Show_status(bool value)
    {
        //Your implementation here
    }
}
```

Script3 called `ObjectToClick3`.

```
public class ObjectToClick3 : MonoBehaviour, IClickable
{
    //Implement your interface function
    public void Show_status(bool value)
    {
        //Your implementation here
    }
}
```

...

...

Now, for the clicking part and detecting which Object is clicked:

```
public class ObjectTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform current_transform;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //Raycast from mouse cursor pos
            RaycastHit rayCastHit;
            Ray rayCast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(rayCast, out rayCastHit))
            {
                IClickable tempIClickable = rayCastHit.transform.GetComponent<IClickable>();
                if (tempIClickable != null)
                {
                    tempIClickable.Show_status(true);
                    current_transform.GetComponent<IClickable>().Show_status(false);
                    current_transform = rayCastHit.transform;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can add as many interface as possible. This is very flexible and can  be used to detect types of enemies available.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong, the Unity [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) class does not have a method named `Show_status`.

You must cast the `Component` returned by `GetComponent` to your custom class. Example:

```
CustomClass yourClass = hit.transform.GetComponent(hit.transform.name) as CustomClass;

if(yourClass) {
    yourClass.Show_status(true);
}
```

See: [`GameObject.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

Comment: The "CustomClass" is unknown till the player clicks the gameObject. We can store every possible class somewhere and check through them. But I am looking for a simpler solution for the issue.

Comment: Then this comes down to a design/architecture problem in your project. Do you really need 10 completely unique classes (one for each object)? It seems they all have at least `Show_status` in common, so perhaps you can combine identical features into a parent class. Then you cast the component to the parent class, and then depending on the status or whatever other criteria, cast it to the child unique implementation. It is hard to say what the best strategy is without knowing more about the overall design (which would be beyond the scope of this question).

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the result of `GetComponent()` to a class to access its methods - but in your situation, you don't know which script is attached to the GameObject being clicked.

This is one of those cases where inheritance provides a possible solution (the alternative would be to make the status tracking a separate component entirely). Since you have a method which is common between multiple classes, why not just have them all inherit from a class which has that method? Then you don't need to differentiate between which one specifically is on the GameObject being clicked.

So your base class might look like:

```
public class StatusTracker : MonoBehaviour {
    public virtual void Show_status(bool status){
        // Status-changing code
    }
}
```

Then the classes you'd actually attach to your GameObjects as components would inherit from `StatusTracker` and have the form of:

```
public class SpecializedStatusTracker : StatusTracker {
    public override void Show_status(bool status){
        // Alternative status-changing code
    }
}
```

*Note: You only need to override Show_status() if your class implements it differently from the generic Show_status() - otherwise, you don't even need to define the method in the child class(es)!*

Adapting your raycast code accordingly, you can then cast the returned `Component` to the parent class `StatusTracker` (using the generic variant of `GetComponent()`) like so:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
    hit.transform.GetComponent<StatusTracker>().Show_status (true);
    current_transform.GetComponent<StatusTracker>().Show_status(false);
    current_transform = hit.transform;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.